# boost::variant<T> to std::string

Tags: c++, string, variant

I have a boost variant of looking like this: `typedef boost::variant<int, float, double, long, bool, std::string, boost::posix_time::ptime> variant;`

I have a need for being able to convert any of the values in this variant to a std::string, I wondered if there is some template type function I could use to do this?

Or what would be the most effective way?

I would currently implement a bunch of overloaded functions, each taking a type and then doing the conversion using `std::stringstream` or for `posix_time` i'd use it's conversion function.  Perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm?sess=40eeb38f681b328a276027a075cd91e8), which hides the whole `stringstream` thing behind a convenient wrapper. This also works with boost::posix_time, since it has a suitable `operator<<`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
struct to_string_visitor : boost::static_visitor<>
{
  std::string str; 

  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T const& item)
  {
    str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(item);
  }
  void operator()(boost::posix_time::ptime const & item)
  {
    //special handling just for ptime
  }
};

int main(){
  variant v = 34;
  to_string_visitor vis;
  boost::apply_visitor(vis, v);
  cout << vis.str << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok, changed. I didn't compiled this.

Comment: Nice one! Powerful usage of overloading.

Answer (score 1):

See [generically convert from boost::variant<T> to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365747/generically-convert-from-boostvariantt-to-type). You should be able to adapt that answer to your situation. You can use `boost::lexical_cast` for all your types except the `boost::posix_time::ptime` where you probably need to do a special solution. All of this in the `static_visitor` using operator overloading (template + one for the ptime).

Answer (score 0):

a cleaner and more elegant (but not more efficient) way to convert a certain type into `std::string` is to use

`template<typename Target, typename Source> Target lexical_cast(const Source& arg);`

from

`#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>`

The type to be converted needs to provide the usual "<<" operator for ostream.

example usage:
`std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( 17 );
assert( s == "17" );`

Comment: Actually it can also be more efficient (boost should use a stack array for the stream buffer if the maximum length of a type's string representation is known at compile-time). But the question was about `boost::variant`.